How to query WebSphere Node Agent status from CLI
Is there any way to get the status of the IBM WebSphere Node Agent from the CLI. I am working on a Python script to automate the status checking, but I haven't found a command (yet) that will help me get the status of the Node Agent from the terminal.
Thanks in advance for all the help!

The serverStatus command should get you what you want: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/9.0.5?topic=tools-serverstatus-command
The Node Agent is a server named "nodeagent", so "serverStatus nodeagent" should provide the output you're looking for.
